# How to refer to a local path in an OS-friendly way?

Tags: php

In PHP how do you refer to files in an OS friendly manner? I'm looking at some code like

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/common/config.inc.php');

...
```

that I have to run on a Windows machine, but it doesn't parse the path right:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\workspace/common/config.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\workspace\somescript.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\workspace/common/config.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\workspace\somescript.php on line 2
```

It looks like it's trying to open with the forward-slashes which windows doesn't like. The file C:\workspace\commonconfig.inc.php exists. The script is just not finding it because it has the forward-slashes right?

In the require_once statement, shouldn't I be expressing the last part of the path in some os-friendly way? How do you do that?

In PHP, is there something similar to Python's   [os.path.normpath(path)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) ? ..which takes a path-like string and returns the path appropriate to the running OS...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things you could use.

Instead of hardcoding the slashes, use the built-in constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, or as I prefer, make your own:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

..it makes your code a bit more compact.

Alternatively, use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath) and express all your paths with unix-style forward slashes, since:

> On windows realpath() will change unix style paths to windows style.
>   `<?php
>   echo realpath('/windows/system32');
>   ?>`
>
> The above example will output:
>   `C:\WINDOWS\System32`

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/the/rest/of/yr/path/and/file.php"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
$dir = str_replace("\\", '/', dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once $dir . '/common/config.inc.php';
```

Works on both Windows and Linux. Although in this case, why not just do:

```
require_once '../common/config.inc.php';
```

?

Comment: just a note to anyone who stumbles on this, str_replace is (match_string, replace_string, target), so switch the first 2 params: str_replace("/", "\\", dirname(dirname(__FILE__));